# Angularjs count increment

Tags: angularjs, button, click, counter, angularjs-ng-click

I'd like to have the heart button work on the second slide just like it works on the first. I'm not really sure where to go from here as I'm a beginner at Angularjs. How can I make the button increment by 1 every time someone clicks on the heart. I'd like to use Angularjs and not JQuery if possible.

```
<div class="socialshare">
      <div ng-app ng-class="socialshare"> <a ng-init="counter = 423" ng-click="counter = counter + 1" class="btn btn-social"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a> {{counter}} </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tiffsaw/6y5Ltvev/):

Answer (score 0):

you need to move the ng-init onto the wrapping div

```
<div class="socialshare">
    <div ng-app ng-class="socialshare" ng-init="counter = 423">
        <a ng-click="counter = counter + 1" class="btn btn-social">
        <i ng-click="counter = counter + 1" class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        </a> 
        {{counter}}
     </div>
 </div>
```

then you will have access to counter on any HTML element inside the div
so you can add an ng-click to the heart also

cheers

(alternatively you could just put the ng-click on the wrapping div)

Comment: Thanks @danday74 for your help but it still doesn't work. On the other slides, the counter doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/2gnabqvo/). I made minimum changes as possible but as you learn more you should start using controller to handle all logic rather than embedding everything inside html. You can definitely improve the code in demo.

You need to move ng-app attribute to container level and define ng-controller at slides level so that it can have its own scope.

```
    <div class="container"  ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="nav"> 
            <span class="left fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x"></span>
            <span class="right fa fa-chevron-right fa-3x"></span>
        </div>
    <div class="slides" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div class="left-content">
         <blockquote></blockquote>
          <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/if00ntv27/sheldon_1.png"  alt="Sheldon"> 
       </div>
     <div class="right-content">
      <div class="socialshare">
        <div ng-app ng-class="socialshare"> <a ng-init="counter = 423" ng-click="counter = counter + 1" class="btn btn-social"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a> {{counter}} </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quote-content">
        <div class="quote">
          <p>Don’t you think that if I were wrong, I’d know it?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="author">- Sheldon Cooper</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="left-content">
      <blockquote></blockquote>
      <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/w2ao9sein/samberg_1.png" alt="Sheldon"> </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <div class="socialshare">
        <div ng-app ng-class="socialshare"> <a ng-init="counter = 423" ng-click="counter = counter + 1" class="btn btn-social"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a> {{counter}} </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quote-content">
        <div class="quote">
          <p>I'm a story teller, Sir. It's my craft!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="author">- Detective Jake Perralta - aka Lone Wolf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add following script.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you!! I definitely want to learn more about Angularjs!

Comment: @user3451161: You are welcome. Please mark it as an answer if it helped you.